# NodeJS - Match JSON Arrays and send email to user - Gives empty coins arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming

I'm new to NodeJS and started to build out a serverless function to

1. Match custom_alerts criteria to crypto_signals data and send an email to the user.

I'm stuck in my loop trying to for that email combine all matching customAlerts and then create an array that matches customAlerts.signals_selection to cryptoSignals.combo_signal

The issue is here (see all code below for context) since one is an array and one is not

```
customObject.coins = cryptoSignalList.filter(item => item.combo_signal == x.signals_selection.includes(item))
```

I'm trying to use filter, reduce stuff for the first time.

Current Output

```
 [
    { name: 'only Very Positive', coins: [] },
    { name: 'Only negative', coins: [] }
  ]
```

**Output Goal**

To send an email to the user with all the coins that match their criteria from custom_alerts. To create the email I'm thinking In the loop create an array that looks like below so I can use that in the body of the email

```
[
    {
        "name": customAlerts.name
        "coins": [
            {
                "coin": cryptoSignals.coin,
                "combo_signal": cryptoSignals.combo_signal
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        "name": customAlerts.name
        "coins": [
            {
                "coin": cryptoSignals.coin,
                "combo_signal": cryptoSignals.combo_signal
            }
        ]

    }
]
```

Data examples

Cryptosignals output example

```
[{
    id: 119,
    coin: 'iExec RLC',
    coin_abr: 'RLC',
    combo_signal: 'Negative',
    combo_change: true,
    combo_prev_signal: 'Very Negative'
  }
]
```

customAlerts output example

```
[{
    id: 8,
    created_at: '2022-03-01T07:58:48.963809+00:00',
    user_id: 'test12345',
    signals_selection: [ 'Very Positive', 'Positive' ],
    categories_selection: [ 'combo_signal' ],
    name: 'Only Positive',
    profiles: { email: 'email@email.com' }
  }
]
```

My code

```
const matchAlertSignal = (emailList, customAlertList, cryptoSignalList) => {
    const testArray = []
    for (let i of emailList) { //loop through the email list
        const emailAlertFilter = customAlertList.filter((customAlertList) => customAlertList.profiles.email == i )
        const filterArray = [] 
        
        for(let x of emailAlertFilter) {
            const customObject = {}
            customObject.name = x.name
            customObject.coins = cryptoSignalList.filter(item => item.combo_signal == x.signals_selection.includes(item))
            filterArray.push(customObject)
       }
        testArray.push(filterArray)
    }
    console.log(testArray)
}


async function main(){
    let cryptoSignals = await getCryptoSignals();
    let customAlerts = await getCustomAlerts();
    let supabaseEmails = userEmail(customAlerts);
    let customFilter = matchAlertSignal(supabaseEmails, customAlerts, cryptoSignals);
```

Comment: _`const emailAlertFilter = customAlertList.filter(`…`)`_ — [`filter`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array. Arrays do not have a `signals_selection` property, so `emailAlertFilter.signals_selection` is `undefined`, explaining the error.

Comment: Yes, you are right, would you know how I can adjust my function for the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with the current version of your question:

1. `matchAlertSignal`does not return a value
2. The filtering on `cryptoSignalList` seems incorrect as you test equality between `combo_signal` (string) and the fact that the `emailAlertFilter.signals_selection` contains the value (boolean).

I would suggest the following:

```
const matchAlertSignal = (emailList, customAlertList, cryptoSignalList) => {
  for (let i of emailList) { //loop through the email list
    const emailAlertFilter = customAlertList.filter((customAlertList) => customAlertList.profiles.email === i )
    const filterArray = [] 
    const customObject = {}
    for(let x of emailAlertFilter) {
      customObject.name = x.name
      customObject.coins = cryptoSignalList.filter((combo_signal) => x.signals_selection.includes(combo_signal))
      filterArray.push(customObject)
    }
  }
  return filterArray
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Copy pasting your code I get ReferenceError: filterArray is not defined, I suppose return FilterArray should be moved one level up

Comment: Still getting [
  { name: 'only Very Positive', coins: [] },
  { name: 'Only negative', coins: [] }
]
[ { name: 'Only Positive', coins: [] } ]

To clarify above: combo_signal is a string and x.signal_selection is an array